# Why does my microwave turn on other battery powered electronics?

Tags: batteries, microwaves, ghosts

Situation: I have a 8-10 yr old LG microwave in a small alcove built into the cabinetry of our kitchen counter. I have a pretty cheap Bomata battery powered coffee scale that I store on the countertop situated above the microvave's alcove. So there is 3 inch air gap, 5/8" wood and 3/4" granite between the top of the microwave and where the scale is kept.

Issue: occasionally when I run the microwave, the scale turns on by itself. It has never turned on by itself otherwise. When it happens, it happens within the first few seconds of the microwave turning on.

How could the microwave be causing the scale to turn on?

Comment: my microwave  interferes with the weighing on a scale with battery.  to get a correct  reading  I have a distance from the microwave. I think the spill out microwaves interfere with the electronics of the scale for weighing.

Comment: see the answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18471/can-microwaves-affect-wifi/18485#18485

Comment: As a recall, the maximum FDA permissible microwave leakage measured 2 cm from any external surface of the oven over its lifetime is 5 mw/cm$^2$. You may want to have your oven checked out for leakage.